# Hyperledger Composer / EACCES: permission denied

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

When I run `Hyperledger` Composer Project runner this is the error I get
I also get the same error when I use node-red `hyperledger` composer nodes in node-red. But I am able to create blocks using Swagger API which is generated by the REST `API` created by `Hyperledger` composer.

Error: Error trying login and get user Context.

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/amarjeetsinghmundi/.composer-credentials/0e69a271fc424d83045600059f44aa23d06eefba78c8acf660f0da5e5397309b-pub'
>           at client.getUserContext.then.then.catch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-hyperledger-composer/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:292:34)

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is some sort of Linux permissions issue (e.g. running or installing npm modules using `sudo`). You should NOT use `sudo` when performing npm install or running composer commands.